# Reference Request: Overlaps between complexity theory and dynamical systems?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-foundations, physics

Per Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, a dynamical system is a system in which a function
>   describes the time dependence of a point in a geometrical space.
>   Examples include the mathematical models that describe the swinging of
>   a clock pendulum, the flow of water in a pipe, and the number of fish
>   each springtime in a lake.
>
> At any given time a dynamical system has a state given by a set of
>   real numbers (a vector) that can be represented by a point in an
>   appropriate state space (a geometrical manifold). The evolution rule
>   of the dynamical system is a function that describes what future
>   states follow from the current state. Often the function is
>   deterministic; in other words, for a given time interval only one
>   future state follows from the current state however, some
>   systems are stochastic, in that random events also affect the
>   evolution of the state variables.

Is there any result on dynamical system (i.e. solving dynamical equations, finding asymptotic states to a system, dynamics in chaotic system) with complexity theory, hardness for finding a solution, etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-researched area. For a representative result, see [Kawamura's proof](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4622) that solving ODEs is difficult.

A different line of works studies the hardness of computing Nash equilibria and related problems. See for example the recent breakthrough of [Bitansky, Paneth and Rosen](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2015/001/download/), who base hardness of cryptographic assumptions; [earlier work](http://people.csail.mit.edu/costis/simplified.pdf) based it on complexity theoretic assumptions.